# Perspective projection matrix in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, geometry, projection-matrix

I an new to perspective division phenomenon. I am rendering a simple square in 3D space using following code :

```
    void MatrixPersp(Mat4& matrix,const float fovy, const float aspect, const float zNear, const float zFar)
    {
         float sine, cotangent, deltaZ;
         float radians;

         for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
             for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
             {
                 if(i==j)
                    matrix[i][j]=1.0;
                 else
                     matrix[i][j]=0.0;
             }

         radians = fovy / 2 * GLES_Pi / 180;

         deltaZ = zFar - zNear;
         sine = (float) sin(radians);

         cotangent = (float) cos(radians) / sine;

         matrix[0][0] = cotangent / aspect;
         matrix[1][1] = cotangent;
         matrix[2][2] = -(zFar + zNear) / deltaZ;
         matrix[2][3] = -1;
         matrix[3][2] = -2 * zNear * zFar / deltaZ;
         matrix[3][3] = 0;

         return;    
    }

void Render()
{
    GLfloat vertices[] = 
    {
        -0.8,0.6,1.0,1.0,
        -0.8,0.2,1.0,1.0,
         0.2,0.2,1.0,1.0,
        0.2,0.6,1.0,1.0
    };

    MatrixPersp(perspective,90.0,aspect,2.0,100.0);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program_object,"MVPMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)perspective);

    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);


glDrawElements();
```

}

Vertex Shader is :

```
#version 150

in vec4 position;

uniform mat4 MVPMatrix;

void main()
{
        gl_Position = position*MVPMatrix;

}
```

The problem here is that , when all the four vertices have same z-value nothing is rendered at all. On the other hand if two vertices have -1 as z-coordinate the projection matrix works fine. 
I am not sure what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program_object,"MVPMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)perspective);
```

This line suggests that your matrix is in column-major order. This is confirmed by the way your `MatrixPersp` function computes its matrix, depending on exactly how `Mat4` is defined.

```
gl_Position = position*MVPMatrix;
```

If `MVPMatrix` is properly column-major, then this multiplication is *backwards.* The position goes on the right.

Comment: @maverick9888 Something should still have changed. Did the *same* error occur, or did something new happen?

Comment: @Hydronium  : Unfortunately there is no error in shader compilation. Nothing new happened :-(

Comment: @maverick9888 Well this would be a logical error, not a technical one. OpenGL won't complain about how you do your math, but your actual output vs your expected output should make you complain. Have you tried the same two cases that you mentioned in your post? Draw with vertices at the same Z coordinates and then draw with some at -1?

Comment: @Hydronium : I tried that combination as well. Still not sure whats going wrong. Same results i.e. no output !

Comment: @maverick9888 Change all four Z-coordinates from 1.0 to 0.9 and tell me what you see. Also try -0.9 for all four.